GitHub does not deploy page after succesful dployment run
I am trying to deploy to GitHub-Pages with the following workflow, which runs sucessful, without any errors. However, the site does not get deployed. You can checkout out my repository here: https://github.com/felmade/OWASP-Calculator/tree/master. Also in the log files, no errors are shown? Has somebody had something familiar?
name: Build and Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Run tests
        run: npm test

      - name: Prepare publish directory
        run: |
          mkdir public
          cp index.html public/
          cp -r css public/
          cp -r js public/
          cp -r img public/
          cp -r assets public/

      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v4
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: public
          publish_branch: gh-pages
          force_orphan: true


Did you enable it in the repo settings?
